# How to auto remove/kick members from telegram channel or group?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have telegram channel/group where i add members manually and i remove/kick users manually after one/two/three month. Is there any way to do this task automatically, I mean can we remove/kick user from channel/group automatically or by scheduling?

Any sample python code will help for understanding. Thank you...!

Answer (score 1):

You can ban a user from a group for a predefined amount of time using [kick_chat_member](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/kick_chat_member). The function will return `True` if the user is successfully removed.

```
        # kick a user from a group
        m = context.bot.kick_chat_member(
        chat_id="-1001572091573", 
        user_id='123456789',
        timeout=int(time.time() + 86400)) # expiry after 24h
```

You need to obtain the `chat_id` of the Group chat and the `user_id` of the user to ban: you can do that by intercepting events like `new_chat_members` which provides all the information when a new user is added to the group

```
# handler to process new member event
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(
     MessageHandler(Filters.status_update.new_chat_members, new_member))

def new_member(update, context):
  logging.info(f"new_member : {update}")

  chat_id = update.message.chat.id
  user_id = update.message.from_user.id
```

The bot needs to be able to perform this type of operation, so make sure it is an admin or has the `ban user` privilege.

**Scheduling**

Scheduling operations like that are (obviously) not covered by the Telegram BOT API, but it is logic that the application/chatbot should implement.

You need to take care of the following:

- obtain the chat_id (see above) and save it for later user
- save member IDs (see above) when they join the group, together with the date (to be able to establish how long they have been part of the group)

A good way to implement tasks in Python is to use [Advanced Python Scheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

scheduler.add_job(ban_members, 'interval', days=30) 
scheduler.start()

def ban_members():

   # get users from DB
   # establish who needs to be removed
   # call kick_chat_member
```

Comment: They didn't mean banning for a specific period of time. They meant scheduling a ban. So if a user joins the group, they get banned after a month.

Comment: I have added sample code to implement background task banning users after a given period. Note: this is custom application logic so it is not part of the Telegram Chatbot API or event the REST Telegram.

Comment: @VikaS GuttE I think my answer should provide you with the solution you are looking for (if you use the Python Telegram API library). I can elaborate/clarify further if needed.

Comment: @BeppeC - I tried above one but not sure somthing is wrong, also i am not sure where and how i can store the user details. do you have any working code or sample example? I am trying this on https://replit.com/ for your infomation. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can look at https://github.com/gcatanese/SampleTelegramQuiz. It is a Sample Telegram Chatbot with the code to perform various replies. Once you get the `user_id` and the `chat_id` you need to store them somewhere (DB, file) so the background task can use them when it runs

Comment: You could try first to implement the backend task hardcoding the `chat_id` and the `user_id`, once it works you can solve the next problem (where to store these IDs and how to fetch them)

Answer (score 1):

Due to Official Telegram Bot API [docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#banchatmember), it's not possible to schedule a [banChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#banchatmember).

What you can do is to register users in a database including a field called `kick_date` and have cron jobs run a script to check if their `kick_date` is before current time and use `banChatMember` to ban them.

---

I didn't post any codes since your question;

1. looked like as if you are looking for a method in Telegram's API.
2. You haven't mentioned which Python Telegram bot API you want to use.
3. Giving code sample for your question (ignoring  both 1 & 2 reasons), would be a project for itself since it consists of different sections of code. I suggest you divide your question to these parts and search/ask about them:

- How to store current members in a database?
- How to store new members in a database?
- How to run a script on Python periodically?
- How to kick members by id?

I'm gonna give you the steps you can take to achieve your goal.

1. Upon adding a member to your group you will get an Update from Telegram including the field `new_chat_members`:

```
{
      "update_id": 436022554,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 259,
        "from": {
          "id": <user_id>,
          "is_bot": false,
          "first_name": <user_first_name>,
          "username": <user_username>,
          "language_code": "en"
        },
        "chat": {
          "id": <chat_id>,
          "title": <chat_title>,
          "type": "group",
          "all_members_are_administrators": true
        },
        "date": 1633373553,
        "new_chat_members": [
          {
            "id": <chat_member_id>,
            "is_bot": false,
            "first_name": <chat_member_first_name>,
            "username": <chat_member_username>
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

2. You're gonna iterate through `new_chat_members` and add them to your database along with a `kick_at` time.
3. Write a script to get your members from the database and check if it's time to kick them. (`kick_at` < `now`) and use [banChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#banchatmember) for that matter.

Comment: @Ali can you help me with any sample code. Thank you for your help...!

Comment: @VikaSGuttE I updated the answer with more details. Feel free to ask a more detailed question to get an exact sample code. As you saw 2 people were confused and gave wrong and misleading answers to your question, which is why I think I'm not the only one with this thought that the question is not specific.

Answer (score 0):

you can schedule any action using `python-telegram-bot`,
and can also schedule `kick_chat_member`
**Read Full Documentation Here**
https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io

Comment: do you have any working example or video to implement `kick_chat_member`, sorry I am new to python so don't know how to use this and impletement on Telegram. Thank you for your help...!

Comment: scheduling a `kick_chat_member` is not possible

Comment: it's possible if you get time every 5 minute and always check for that time when you want to kick,